# getting two column values from same table depending on the condition

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two tables:

```
table product1 with columns:
    product_id 
    prodcut_name
    category_id
```

```
another table  categories 
    category_id
    category_name
    category_description
```

I am populating product details using `DataGridView` and it's working fine.

I am trying to get the two column values from same table depending on the same condition that I have got  the code below:

```
string desc = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["productdescr"].Value);
string productname = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["productnam"].Value);
string productprices = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["productprice"].Value);
int  productids = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells["productid"].Value);
```

**condition 1:**

```
int  categoryids = (from cats in tsg.product1
                    where cats.product_Name.Equals(productname)
                    select cats.category_Id).SingleOrDefault();
```

**condition 2:**

```
var catogynames = (from categorytypes in tsg.categories
                   where categorytypes.category_Id.Equals(categoryids)
                   select  categorytypes.category_Name
                  ).SingleOrDefault();
```

**condition 3:**

```
var categoprydecription = (from categorytable in tsg.categories
                           where categorytable.category_Id.Equals(categoryids)
                           select categorytable.category_Description
                          ).SingleOrDefault();
```

I want to get the `categorytypes.category_description` also along with this  `categorytypes.category_Name` from the **condition 2**, is it possible to combine the two conditions? (condition 2 and condition 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in this fashion

```
(from categorytable in tsg.categories
where categorytable.category_Id == categoryids
select new {Name=categorytable.category_Name, 
            Description=categorytable.category_Description}).SingleOrDefault();
```

This will be an anonymous class holding both name and description of the categories you want.

Comment: change the where condition to `categorytable.category_Id == categoryids`